# How to remove 1st empty column from file using bash commands?

Tags: linux, bash

I have output file that can be read by a visualizing tool, the problem is that at the beginning of each line there is one space. Because of this the visualizing tool isn't able to recognize the scripts and, hence crashing. When I manually remove the first column of spaces, it works fine. Is there a way to remove the 1st empty column of spaces using bash command [image: First Image is the one where there is an excess column of empty spaces]

What I want is to remove the excess column of empty space like shown in this second image using a bash command[image: Second Image]

At present I use Vim editor to remove the 1st column manually. But I would like to do it using a bash command so that I can automate the process. My file is not just full of columns, it has some independent data line

Comment: See [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` or `sed` would be two simple solutions.

#### cut

```
cut -c2- file > file.cut && mv file.cut file
```

`cut` cannot modify a file, therefore you need to redirect its output to a different file and then overwrite the old file with the new file.

#### sed

```
sed -i 's/^.//' file
```

`-i` modifies the file *in-place*.

Comment: Note that both of these will remove the first character from a line, regardless of whether it is a space or not.  The sed command could instead just remove spaces, leaving lines that don't being with a space alone, by using the pattern `/^ /` instead of `/^./`

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
sed -ie 's/^ //' file
```

to just remove spaces (in case a line does not contain it)

Comment: it probably depends on the sed version, but on macOS: "-i extension Edit files in-place" (which is the one I tested on)

Comment: No worries, it happens